# Why does Zampa take the blame for Pierre Michel's murder?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-connection

In *[La French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Connection_%282014_film%29)* (The Connection) 2014 French film, Tany's associates are jailed after the heroin lab is busted and one of them comes up with a plan to organise Pierre Michel's murder on the outside by a couple of guys on a motorbike and they say that this will somehow solve their problem of being in jail and that Tany will have to take the fall.

When Tany is informed that Pierre Michel has been murdered he knows that he will be in trouble for it.

But I don't understand, he had nothing to do with the murder, so why does he take the fall for a murder that he did not commit and did not organise?